# .Net Application as Azure Web Job not writing on disk

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I have a .net core 2.2 console application with build platform x86 that simply calls a unmanaged dll that returns a bool of the result and this dll also writes on disk a txt file named 'OMNISCHEDULERLIB.LOG', while on debug locally I can run it and the function executes properly and prints out on the console the result boolean off the dll.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = ProcessJobs();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("Output/OmniSchedulerLIB.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "ProcessJobs")]
    private static extern bool ProcessJobs();
}
```

This is the code of my Program.cs file which calls the dll correctly locally and generates on folder Output the 'OMNISCHEDULERLIB.LOG'.
When I deployed it to azure as an WebJob of an AppService the webjob prints out on the console the result correctly but no log file is created under the output folder ( I have checked via ftp and the Kudu tool ).
What I don't understand is that if i go on Kudu tool and on the webjob directory and run my .exe of the console application via cmd 'start myapp.exe' I get the result on the console and the .log file is created under the Output folder on my webjob.

My question is what command is the azure webjob running to execute my .net core console, and how is it preventing from writing on the disk, or any other explanation to this situation?

Edit: after going into D:\home\data\logs\ I was able to find which script is running

```
[03/13/2019 10:05:00 > a87042: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[03/13/2019 10:05:05 > a87042: SYS INFO] Run script 'OmniManager.OmniSchedulerWebJob.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[03/13/2019 10:05:05 > a87042: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/13/2019 10:05:10 > a87042: INFO] True
[03/13/2019 10:05:10 > a87042: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

But the .log file isn't generated there, but if i run mannually the command from the kudu's cmd 'start OmniManager.OmniSchedulerWebJob.exe' It will return the same above outcome 'True' but with the .log file generated. I have tried with no success adding a run.cmd to run my dotnet console application dll but It seems I get an error since I can't run it from a x86 platform and I haven't found a way to run the 'dotnet' command while choosing a x86 sdk of .net but my exe will execute in 32 bit.

Comment: Can you try writing file log in just after this line var result = ProcessJobs(); and see if it works and create new file? Also you can actually see the logs in KUDU for the same, You will be able to see what command and exe it is actually executing. Can you try and see if it gives some usefull info.

Comment: I have edited my question with inputs from your aswner and @joey-cai

Comment: Please refer the answer posted by Joey cai, and see if helps. My next point was the same to use the path data\logs\OMNISCHEDULERLIB.log instead of directly adding the log filder name output.

Comment: The problem is that i'm calling a dll that I have no source code neither i can choose where it writes by default it will write on the Output folder , which is doing correctly by running the exe with the cmd command on the Kudu , but when the webjob runs by himself on schedule or manual it wont generate that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently since I was able to get the expected output .log file by running .exe of the .net core application (I published as self contained to work as x86) via the kudu powershell tool the workaround was to add a run.cmd file to the webjob with the command `'cmd /c myapplication.exe'` so that it would the result of the boolean returned by the dll operation and as well allowing the dll to write on the webjob directory.
All the answers weren't enough to reach my solution since they provided useful links that I already crossed before making this question but I appreciate all the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dotnet consolecorewebjob.dll` to run the console core application. For more details, you could refer to the article about [How to deploy a .NET Core console application to Azure, WebJob](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/).

You could try to see the log under `D:\home\data\logs\OMNISCHEDULERLIB.log`.

Comment: Running the dotnet command directly to my dll will reproduce the following error 'External component has thrown an exception' I assume is that i can't a x86 platform dll in a sdk x64 which i can't find a option in the dotnet -h to choose the x86 sdk version

Comment: You could refer to this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7532#issuecomment-330706524) which will pick up correct sdk version automatically for projects.

Comment: Or you could go to `OmniSchedulerLIB` project and click `properties> build>platform target` to x64

Comment: Yes that link was how I initially was able to be able to debug my application in 32 bit and call the dll it doesn't solves my question since my application works simply the dll is not able to write on disk , and I cant compile the dll in 64 bit becayse the source code I'm not responsible for or access to.